# has anybody used delta compression for json data in android

Tags: android, json, node.js, performance

I have been trying to reduce the json data footprint that we are using in our android native application the file sizes for which are generally huge.

This has led me to believe that to achieve optimisations for json the following can be done

1) json minimization

2) compression algorithm like gzip or lzw (not sure which one will be better)

3) horizontal delta compression wherein we send only the difference/delta between two subsequent json files that greatly reduces the amount of data we send over the wire.

Please share your views if you guys have done or experimented with any of these techniques for json compression. Also we use node.js as the backend for the server side apis.

Answer (score 2):

As for delta compression, you may want to look at http://jsonpatch.com

> JSON Patch is a format for describing changes to a JSON document. It can be used to avoid sending a whole document when only a part has changed. When used in combination with the HTTP PATCH method it allows partial updates for HTTP APIs in a standards compliant way.

As you're using Node, you can take a look at [JSON-Patch](https://www.npmjs.org/package/fast-json-patch) which will not only apply patches to a document/object but also has the ability to observe an object and generate a patch for you once it's been modified.